"useState" is not exported by "node_modules/react/index.js", imported by "src/pages/LoginForm.jsx"
I've been facing an issue where every time I try to run the command npm run build for my project, I get an error saying, "useState" is not exported by "node_modules/react/index.js", imported by "src/pages/LoginForm.jsx". I've tried several ways to resolve this, including verifying my imports in LoginForm.jsx to ensure I am correctly importing useState with import React, { useState } from 'react';, but the error persists. I also checked to make sure my react and react-dom dependencies are installed and up-to-date by running npm install react react-dom. When that didn't work, I deleted the node_modules folder and the package-lock.json file to perform a clean reinstallation of dependencies using npm install. Additionally, I tried clearing the Vite cache by removing the .vite folder in node_modules and then running the build again, but I still encountered the same problem. I've double-checked my vite.config.js to ensure it's properly configured for React, particularly for handling modern JSX and hooks. Despite all these attempts, the issue remains unresolved, and I'm unsure if the problem lies with my React setup, Vite configuration, or something else entirely. Could you help me figure out what might be causing this and how to fix it?
src/components/LoginForm.jsx
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth';
import { auth, firestore } from '../firebaseConfig';
import { collection, query, where, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import './LoginForm.css';

const LoginForm = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [error, setError] = useState('');
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const handleLogin = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setError('');
        setLoading(true);

        try {
            // Query Firestore to check if this email belongs to a station admin
            const adminsRef = collection(firestore, 'stationAdmin');
            const q = query(adminsRef, where('stationAdmin_Email', '==', email));
            const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

            if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
                // Email matches admin; proceed with sign-in
                await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
                navigate('/dashboard'); // Redirect to dashboard
            } else {
                setError('Unauthorized access. Only station admins are allowed.');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            setError('Invalid email or password. Please try again.');
        } finally {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className="login-container">
            <form className="login-form" onSubmit={handleLogin}>
                <h1>FlameGuard Station Admin Login</h1>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="email">Email:</label>
                    <input
                        type="email"
                        id="email"
                        value={email}
                        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                        required
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
                    <input
                        type="password"
                        id="password"
                        value={password}
                        onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                        required
                    />
                </div>
                {error && <p className="error-message">{error}</p>}
                <button type="submit" disabled={loading}>
                    {loading ? 'Logging in...' : 'Login'}
                </button>
                <p className="register-link" onClick={() => navigate('/register')}>
                    Register
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};

export default LoginForm;

import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import { NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin } from '@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill';
import { NodeModulesPolyfillPlugin } from '@esbuild-plugins/node-modules-polyfill';
import inject from '@rollup/plugin-inject';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        react(),
        inject({
            // Polyfill for `process` and `Buffer`
            process: 'process/browser',
            Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer'],
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            // Alias for any node module to avoid import errors in the browser
            util: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/util',
            stream: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/stream',
            path: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/path',
        },
    },
    optimizeDeps: {
        esbuildOptions: {
            // Polyfills for node modules used in browser
            define: {
                global: 'globalThis', // This will map global to globalThis for compatibility
            },
            plugins: [
                NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin({
                    process: true,  // Polyfill process
                    buffer: true,   // Polyfill buffer
                }),
                NodeModulesPolyfillPlugin(), // Polyfills for other modules
            ],
        },
    },
});

{
  "name": "flameguard",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill": "^0.2.3",
    "@esbuild-plugins/node-modules-polyfill": "^0.2.2",
    "@google/maps": "^1.1.3",
    "@react-google-maps/api": "^2.20.3",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs": "^4.22.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-tflite": "^0.0.1-alpha.10",
    "axios": "^1.7.7",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "firebase": "^10.14.1",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-geocode": "^1.0.0-alpha.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.27.0",
    "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills": "^0.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@eslint/js": "^9.11.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-inject": "^5.0.5",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.10",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.3.3",
    "eslint": "^9.11.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.37.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^5.1.0-rc.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.12",
    "gh-pages": "^6.2.0",
    "globals": "^15.9.0",
    "rollup": "^4.27.4",
    "vite": "^5.4.11"
  }
}

I try to run build successfully so I can deploy it
npm list react
├─┬ @react-google-maps/api@2.20.3
│ └── react@18.3.1 deduped
├─┬ react-dom@18.3.1
│ └── react@18.3.1 deduped
├─┬ react-router-dom@6.28.0
│ ├─┬ react-router@6.28.0
│ │ └── react@18.3.1 deduped
│ └── react@18.3.1 deduped
└── react@18.3.1


Add your code to CodeSandbox or provide your GitHub link. The code above does not help in recreating the error you mentioned.
